# Assertion failed in PDFTron iOS

Tags: ios, assertion, pdftron

I have integrated the PDFTron library in my iOS Application and followed the instruction mentioned in documentation(**https://blog.pdftron.com/2013/07/19/getting-started-on-ios/**), application is working fine when I am using the local pdf files but application is crashing each time in below scenario

1) Downloaded pdf files from url, stored in document directory and display using the PDFTron.

I have got following the error log:

> function -[PTPDFViewCtrl RemoveAllThumbnails], file
>   /Users/PDFTron/PDFNet_6.5/PDFTron/iOS/Control/PDFViewCtrl.m, line
>   1744. (lldb) bt 
>   * thread #23: tid = 0x12491, 0x000000010aa43002 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill + 10, stop reason = signal
>   SIGABRT
>       frame #0: 0x000000010aa43002 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill + 10
>       frame #1: 0x000000010aa095c5 libsystem_pthread.dylib`pthread_kill + 90
>       frame #2: 0x000000010a799cec libsystem_c.dylib`abort + 129
>       frame #3: 0x000000010a761bdc libsystem_c.dylib`__assert_rtn + 321
>       frame #4: 0x00000001041177c4 BW - Internal`-[PTPDFViewCtrl RemoveAllThumbnails] + 94
>       frame #5: 0x0000000104113daf BW - Internal`-[PTPDFViewCtrl SetDoc:] + 178

I have tried lock and unlocking the document but still I am getting same error and any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

PDFNet can "stream" PDF files from a remote URL using the [OpenURL:](https://www.pdftron.com/pdfnet/mobile/docs/iOS/src/interface_p_t_p_d_f_view_ctrl.html#a2a6b9a451be1ccab7457735519448b1d) method. Are you using this method, or doing it some other way? Either way, please contact us at support@pdftron.com, and we will work with you to sort it out.